# TimeoutError connecting android app to localhost with Volley

Tags: php, android, web-services, xampp, android-volley

I want to make a web service that allow my app to connect with a database in localhost. I'm trying to follow this [example](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/crear-un-webservice-para-android-con-mysql-php-y-json/) making some changes in the names.

In my android code I have this:

```
VolleySingleton.
            getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
            addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constantes.GET, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String result = response.toString();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error.networkResponse == null) {
                        if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                            // Show timeout error message
                            Log.e("error volley",error.getStackTrace().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Oops. Timeout error!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ));
```

*VolleySingleton* class:

```
public final class VolleySingleton {

// Atributos
private static VolleySingleton singleton;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static Context context;


private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    VolleySingleton.context = context;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}
public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new VolleySingleton(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return singleton;
}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

The constants that I have in *Constantes* class:

```
private static final String PUERTO_HOST = "63343";
private static final String IP = "http://10.0.2.2:";
public static final String GET = IP + PUERTO_HOST + "/prueba/obtener_canales.php";
```

I used that ip because I read that 10.0.2.2 is for android studio emulator and 10.0.3.2 is for genymotion.

I'm using XAMPP and the route of my file is "D:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\obtener_canales.php

I'm getting all time the Toast with timeout error and when I debug in android studio there's nothing to see.